# Print path (leaf to root) with max sum in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or more simple.

```
public class MaxSumPath {

    private TreeNode root;

    private static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        int item;

        TreeNode (TreeNode left, TreeNode right, int item) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    private static class TreeInfo {
        TreeNode node;
        int maxCount;

        TreeInfo (TreeNode node, int maxCount) {
            this.node = node;
            this.maxCount = maxCount;
        }
    }

    public void maxSumPath () {
        final TreeInfo treeInfo = new TreeInfo(null, 0);
        fetchMaxSumPath(root, treeInfo, root.item);
        printPath (root, treeInfo);
    }

    private void fetchMaxSumPath (TreeNode node, TreeInfo treeInfo, int sumSoFar) {
        if (node == null) return;

        sumSoFar = sumSoFar + node.item;

        if (node.right == null && node.left == null) {
            if (sumSoFar > treeInfo.maxCount) {
                treeInfo.maxCount = sumSoFar;
                treeInfo.node = node;
            }
            return;
        }

        fetchMaxSumPath(node.left, treeInfo, sumSoFar);
        fetchMaxSumPath(node.right, treeInfo, sumSoFar);
    }

    private boolean printPath (TreeNode node, TreeInfo treeInfo) {
        if (node != null &&  (node == treeInfo.node || printPath(node.left, treeInfo) || printPath(node.right, treeInfo))) {
            System.out.print(node.item + ", ");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also considering additional storage (`TreeInfo`), is it right to say that the space complexity is \$O(1)\$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a constructor `MaxSumPath(TreeNode root)`.  Otherwise, there's no way for any other class to call the code.

The `TreeNode(left, right, item)` constructor is awkward.  Consider rearranging the `TreeNode` constructor arguments to `TreeNode(left, item, right)` or `TreeNode(item, left, right)`.  I suggest creating a `TreeNode(item)` constructor as well.

Your `TreeInfo` could be eliminated by moving its variables into `MaxSumPath` itself.  I'd rename the variables to `TreeNode maxLeaf` and `int maxSum`.

In the `maxSumPath()` method, you call `fetchMaxSumPath(root, treeInfo, root.item)`.  It should be `fetchMaxSumPath(root, treeInfo, 0)` if you don't want to double-count the root node.  (Fortunately, this bug happens not to affect the output.)

The space complexity is actually O(log *n*) when you take into account the stack used in recursion.  The time complexity is O(*n*), because you visit every node once when discovering the leaf for the path with the maximum sum, and every node again to find that leaf for printing.  You might want to use O(log *n*) space (which, remember, happens anyway due to the recursion stack) to keep track of the best path while discovering the best sum, which lets you avoid the second pass O(*n*) pass.

Comment: Agree on constructor, agree on the double counting bug.

Comment: Disagree on - keeping a instance variable for max count, because maintining that value will be complicated if new nodes get added or deleting from tree, I would appreciate if you could highlight if my method had pressing drawbacks, in addition to suggestions.

Comment: Lastly, agree again on complexity, in addition how much space complexity would TreeInfo add ? would it be O(1) ?

Comment: I see no reason to treat what I call `maxLeaf` and `maxSum` any differently from `root`. Either make them all instance variables of `MaxSumPath` (my preferred option), all encapsulated in `TreeInfo`, or pass them all around as local parameters (my least preferred option).

Comment: `TreeInfo` adds O(1) space on top of the O(log _n_) stack that I mentioned, bringing the total space to O(log _n_).

Comment: Correction — O(log _n_) is a best-case scenario, because the tree may not be balanced.  It could be O(_n_) in the worst case.