# Print all path from root to leaves - code review request

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Ok, code reviewers, I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or more simple.

```
public class PrintAllPath {

    private TreeNode root;

    private class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        int item;
        TreeNode right;


        TreeNode (TreeNode left, int item, TreeNode right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.item = item;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    public void create (Integer[] arr) {
        if (arr == null)  {
            throw new NullPointerException("The input array is null.");
        }

        root = new TreeNode(null, null, arr[0]);

        final Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = arr.length / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != null) {
                final TreeNode current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (arr[left] != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode(null, null, arr[left]);
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < arr.length && arr[right] != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode(null, null, arr[right]);
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printPath () {
        doPrint(root, new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
    }


    private void doPrint(TreeNode node, List<TreeNode> path) {
        if (node == null) return;

        path.add(node);

        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            System.out.println("Path from root: " + root.item + " to leaf: " + node.item + " - ");
            for (TreeNode treeNode : path) {
                System.out.print(treeNode.item + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        doPrint(node.left , path);
        doPrint(node.right, path);

        path.remove(path.size() - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good overall.

I see you have taken my [previous suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31931/9357) to rearrange the `TreeNode` constructor arguments.  Now you have to readjust your calling convention accordingly.

Your `create()` method acts like a constructor, so you should just make it a constructor.  It desperately needs a JavaDoc comment explaining how the input array is to be interpreted.

In `create()`, I would not bother to check for `arr == null`.  You'll get a `NullPointerException` anyway when you fetch `arr[0]`.  It's only worth the explicit check if such a check would make debugging substantially easier, i.e. when an improper `null` would get stored or propagated but not dereferenced until much later.  Even then, I'd throw an `IllegalArgumentException` rather than `NullPointerException` to emphasize that the caller is at fault.

In `doPrint()`, `path.remove(path.size() - 1)` should be just `path.removeLast()`.

Comment: Accepted the rest except -  Effective Java mentions to validate each method input, throw exception sooner than later, and use NPE rather than IllegalArgE. I would be receptive if you still have some points to add. Thanks again.

Comment: Cross tallied with SO, you were correct. Thanks for all pointers